# update-alternatives just for one user

Tags: debian, executable, java, non-root-user, alternatives

I'm using a shared server. 
On that server different versions of Java are installed:

```
  Selection    Path                                      Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java   1061      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java       63        manual mode
```

I would like to choose the Second options, but if I tried to do that it complains that I do not have the permissions (I'm not root).

Is there a way to do that in "user-space"?

Can the Root user make this preference works only for me?

Comment: The accepted answer is probably preferrable here but if you genuinely need to use your own alternatives see [my answer at ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/a/811377/3654).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Debian and derivates, you should probably use `update-java-alternatives`. Anyway, all those tools are system related, not user related. If you want to use a different java, simply put those lines in your `~/.profile`:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:"$PATH"
export JAVA_HOME JRE_HOME
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I wanted to chime in with a blatant promotion for the tool I just released that helps you configure per-user (or even per-shell !) alternatives:

- https://github.com/TekWizely/my-alternatives

You can initialize a shell-specific setup:

```
$ eval "$( my-alternatives init)"
```

Or you can initialize a long-lived user-level setup:

```
# run this once
$ eval "$( my-alternatives init ~/my-alts )"

# place this in your startup scripts
$ eval "$( my-alternatives shellenv ~/my-alts )"
```

Once configured, setting up a user-local alternative is as easy as:

```
# equivalent to 'update-alternatives --config <name>'
$ my-alternatives config <name>
```

**NOTE:** At the time of this posting, *my-alternatives* was just released.  As such, only `init` and `config` logic has been built.  Other features will come later.